# SF : query to retrieve duplicates

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

On a **Symfony project**, using php and mysql, i'm trying to get find a way to get all the rows for potential duplicate user looking at two fields only : lastname, firstname.

I have a standard user table :

```
id firstname lastname email otherfield1 ...
1 john smith john.smith@yahoo.fr otherfield1value1 ...
2 john smith john.smith@gmail.com otherfield1value2 ...
3 john doe john.doe@gmail.com otherfield1value3 ...
4 john doe john.doe@gmail.com otherfield1value4 ...
5 jane doe jane.doe@somewhere.com otherfield1value5 ...
```

If i do a :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u1.id) FROM user AS u1 GROUP BY u1.firstName, u1.lastName HAVING count(u1.id) > 1;
```

I get all the duplicates ids as expected

```
1,2
3,4
```

But i would like to have all the info for all the duplicates : id, lastname, firstname but also other fields : email, date of birth...
Using GROUP_CONCAT i can't obviously do :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u1.id), email FROM user AS u1 GROUP BY u1.firstName, u1.lastName HAVING count(u1.id) > 1;
```

This brings me "only" one email by group, as it should (but not as i would like) :

```
1,2 john.smith@yahoo.fr 
3,4 john.doe@gmail.com
```

I can do `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u1.id, ',', u1.email, ',', u1.otherfield SEPARATOR '|') FROM user AS u1 GROUP BY u1.firstName, u1.lastName HAVING count(u1.id) > 1;`
which brings me the complete result :

```
1,john.smith@yahoo.fr,otherfield1value1|2,john.smith@gmail.com,otherfield1value2
3,john.doe@gmail.com,otherfield1value3|4,john.doe@gmail.com,otherfield1value4
```

**but in a non really usable form** : i will have to split twice and loop through the results... Not optimal for Symfony request result.

So i thought of a subquery bringing the ids and using it in a IN clause.
Something like

```
SELECT u.* FROM  user u WHERE u.id IN (THE_SUBQUERY_FOR_DUPLICATE_IDS);
```

But the GROUP_CONCAT request doesn't bring a list of all ids, i get only a list OF GROUP of ids.

```
SELECT u.* FROM  user u WHERE u.id IN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u1.id) FROM user AS u1 GROUP BY u1.firstName, u1.lastName HAVING count(u1.id) > 1
);
```

crashes... since the subquery brings an array.

I would like to know if i can concat the result of the group_concat query, to have a regular list of ids : 1,2,3,4...
or if there is another way to bring in one query all the informations for the duplicated users (and not only the ids) ?

I would rather not have to do the first query, then concat the ids in php, then query for complete result ( = all the fields)

**Of course the request would be best in doctrine language** :), but i could adapt a native mysql query answer if given as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an `INNER JOIN`, for example, try to adapt them like this:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u1.id) var1, (...other variables...) FROM user AS u1 GROUP BY u1.firstName, u1.lastName
INNER JOIN
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u1.id) var2 FROM user AS u1 GROUP BY u1.firstName, u1.lastName HAVING count(u1.id) > 1) duplicates_table
ON user.var1=duplicates_table.var2`

This will get only the results you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but as i showed in my message, this won't work (there is a syntax error if i query (even without the other variable part) because the right part of the INNER JOIN query returns rows like `1,2`, `3,4` and not `1,2,3,4`